# JavaScript "arguments" -passing a function with other parameters

Tags: javascript

Function `multiply` below is passed a callback function "addOne". Function multiply returns [3,5,7].

Since the callback function addOne is one of the arguments of function multiply, and since the arguments of function multiply are all multiplied by 2, why doesnt the callback function itself (i.e. addOne) get multiplied by 2? In other words, instead of function multiply returning `[3,5,7]`, I would have expected it to return `[3,5,7, NAN]` since the function is not a number?

Does JavaScript interpreter just somehow know not to multiply it by 2?

```
function addOne(a) {
return a + 1;
}

function multiply(a,b,c, callback) {
    var i, ar = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ar[i] = callback(arguments[i] * 2);
    }
    return ar;
}



myarr = multiply(1,2,3, addOne);
myarr;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your loop's condition is [`<3`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_%28symbol%29#Computer_code) (hehe) which means it won't subscript the callback (the last element).

You should consider making the callback the first argument always, and splitting the arguments like so...

```
var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
    callback = argumentsArray.shift();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/YN78T/).

Then, `callback` has your callback which you can call with `call()`, `apply()` or plain `()`, and `argumentsArray` has the remainder of your arguments as a proper array.

Comment: I know generally what "call" does, but can you explain how it is working exactly in the example code you wrote. Thank you.

Comment: @mjmitche The `arguments` variable is an object, not an array, although it exposes some array like properties. To be able to call `shift()` on it, we need it as a real array. To do that, we can call the `Array`'s `slice()` on the arguments array, using `call()` to pass the object as `this`. When using `slice()` with no arguments, it returns a copy of the object as an array (or a copy of an array if used on a standard array).

Comment: thanks, so if you need arguments as an array to call shift() on it, and if slice() returns a copy of the object (i.e. arguments) as an array, I don`t understand why you need to use "call() to pass the object as this." Slice turns it into an array, and shift works on the array. Why can`t it be that simple.  If you have time to clarify, please do. Thanks again.

Comment: @mjmitche Because when you do `slice()` normally, the array is `this`. `call()` lets you call a function and set the `this` variable with its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

This line  `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {` is protecting you.

You stop before it hits the `callback` argument

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running the the loop for the first 3 args only. i < 3 runs for i=0, i=1,i=2